# Cakephp 2.x hybridauth google and facebook login redirect url error

Tags: cakephp, facebook-login, redirect, google-signin, hybridauth

I am developing a cakephp 2.x website. I am using hybridauth to login using facebook and google. https://example.com/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google is my redirect url for google and https://example.com/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook for facebook. I am able to login to using facebook and google but some clients are not able to login.

Google Error

```
400. That's an error
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect uri in the request https://example.com/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google does 
not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

But I have given same redirect url in the developers console. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

For Facebook:

```
URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URL is
not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that
the client and web OAuth logins are on and 
add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs
```

any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

To correct these errors, follow these steps:
**For Google:**
1. go to credentials of your app and add your redirect uri, which was similar to this link 
"https://example.com/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google". 
2. Now in your "project>application>config>hybridauthlib.php" add redirect uri like this: 
[image: sample config code] 
**For Facebook**
1. login to developers.facebook.com and open up your app. Now, under products select settings of facebook login from this menu: 
[image: facebook app menu] 
2. add the redirect uri/web url to whitelist here. 
 Now everything should work fine.